# Best Framework for building Social Networking sites with twitter like security

Tags: social-networking

I am looking for framework for building social networking site.

Features:
1) Users can make tweets. Tweets or messages should be available according to security settings such as if user selects only to friend then those tweets should be for only friends.
(or)
Instead of tweets and messages I should say security like public, private, only to friends should be provided.

2) Profile , images, videos should be displayed as per security constraints(only to friends or public).

I found Elgg is best voted in stackoverflow. But I don't know if Elgg provides such kind of features.

Does Elgg framework provides Features mentioned above?

(or)

You would suggest any other best framework with such kind of features.

Please give suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elgg has most of the features you need. The wire plugin coming with elgg package lets you create the tweet like system.